# Value setted to null on flush doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a problem with my code. I am just trying to insert a simple set of data to my db, but doctrine insert my attribute (telVerifCode) as NULL.

I've dumped my data and figured out, that attribute (telVerifCode) has some value in it, but after I flush it is set to NULL.

This is my controller:

```
$user = $this->getUser();

if ($user->getTel() != $tel || $user->getTelCode() != $telCode) {

    try {
        $code = $this->sendTelehopneCode($user);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //.......
    }

    // update user phone verifcation fields //
    $user->setTelVerifCode($code);
    $user->setLastTelVerificationCodeDate(new \DateTime());

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
```

My ORM Mapping:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tel_verification_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $telVerifCode;
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_tel_verification_code_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $lastTelVerificationCodeDate;
```

sendTelehopneCode function :

```
private function sendTelehopneCode($user)
{
    $code = strval(rand(100000, 999999));
    $tel = $user->getTelCode() . $user->getTel();
    $msg = 'code:' . $code;

    $twilio = $this->get('twilio.api');
    try {
        $message = $twilio->account->messages->sendMessage(
            "+14*******", // Verified Outgoing Caller ID or Twilio number
            $tel, // The phone number you wish to send a message to
            $msg
        );
    } catch (\Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
        throw $e;
    }

    return $code;
}
```

Comment: Is there any data type mismatch between original data and orm config (string)?

Comment: $code is a string data

Comment: Then it doesn't make sense to be `null` on `flush()`. Can you put all code from that method in controller?

Comment: i have added the method

Comment: Please dump `$user` object after `persist` and see if the `$code` is set to `User` object. If no, check setter (`setTelVerifCode()`).

Comment: i have dump $user before and after flush :
before flush my attribute (telVerifCode) is setted
after flush my attribute (telVerifCode) is null
no problem with (lastTelVerificationCodeDate)

setter :
    public function setTelVerifCode($telVerifCode)
    {
        $this->telVerifCode = $telVerifCode;

    }

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all! I created a replica of this scenario except the `twilio.api` service. and its working for me.

Comment: i now that doesn't make sense at all! hhhh 
it's been two days that I try, it made me crazy :(

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your doctrine caches, the code looks fine and cannot be the issue.

```
./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I made a listener On preUpdate one that puts the value null, I completely forgotten it :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is due to a typo in your setter.
Are you sure your setter `setTelVerifCode` looks exactly like this?

```
public function setTelVerifCode($code)
{
    $this->telVerifCode = $code;
}
```

Comment: yes absolutely my setter looks exactly like this

public function setTelVerifCode($telVerifCode) { $this->telVerifCode = $telVerifCode; }